# How to publish swagger editor left window as documentation

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I want to publish the right side panel of the swagger editor.

Currently, the team has to share the yaml file and each user has to copy & paste the text into the swagger editor to view the right panel rendering.

Is there a way to publish the content to html so that a page would look like the right panel ?

Example swagger editor windown with formated look on the right:
http://azimi.me/presentations/building-swagger-editor/images/swagger-ui.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to publish it right from the swagger editor but you can use swagger-ui. All you need is to

1. [download](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui) swagger-ui
2. host it on a web server that is accessible for your team
3. save your swagger documentation code to a new file of any filename and host it on your web server, too.
4. tell swagger-ui which documentation file it shall load.

For the last step look for the following piece of code within the swagger-ui's index.html:

```
$(function () {
  var url = window.location.search.match(/url=([^&]+)/);
  if (url && url.length > 1) {
    url = decodeURIComponent(url[1]);
  } else {
    url = "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json";
  }
```

Replace the value of line `url = "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json";` to point to the swagger documentation file you uploaded.